# Как в Qt Creator 3.3.2 указать флаги компиляции для g++`?

Tags: c++, g++, qtcreator

Доброго времени суток! У меня вопрос.

Как в Qt Creator указать флаги компиляции для `g++`? Не для qmake, а именно для g++. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ их указать, кроме как прописывая их в .pro файл проекта?

Comment: а через переменную окружения не получается? вида `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS=...`

Comment: а её добавлять куда? тоже в .pro ?

Comment: нет, я говорю про переменную окружения при вызове qtcreator. у вас какая операционная система? если *gnu/linux*, то можно попробовать запустить программу так: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS="флаги" qrcreator`. если *ms/windows*, то запустить из командной строки, наверно, сложно, поэтому глобально надо определить переменную окружения.

Comment: у меня gnu\linux (ubuntu 14.04). Да, так работает. Спасибо.

Comment: А ещё есть способы? Могу ли я в настройках qt creator(в настройках компиляторов) установить глобальные флаги компиляции для всех проектов?

Comment: увы, не знаю. о `qtcreator` я знаю лишь то, что содержится в её названии — это явно какая-то среда разработки, вероятно, как-то связанная с фреймворком `qt`.

Comment: чтобы не оставлять вопрос неотвеченным, я своё предложение оформил в виде ответа.

Comment: Одно решение найдено, спасибо. Но может быть кто-нибудь знает, как настроить флаги компиляции в настройках компиляторов в Qt Creator ?

Comment: я дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Есть способ. Нужно найти внутри qt файл спецификации `.spec` от вашего комплекта Qt (имя файла написано на закладке Проекты->Сборка, рубрика "Этапы сборки") его использует `qmake` при генерации `Makefile`

В этот файл и нужно дописать опцию.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте запустить программу `qtcreator`, передав ей переменную окружения с нужным вам значением:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS="флаги" qrcreator
```

**дополнение**

если требуется, чтобы такая переменная присутствовала в окружении всегда, то можно добавить её назначение (новой строкой в конце файла), например, в файл `~/.bashrc`, дополнив директивой `export`:

```
export QMAKE_CXXFLAGS="флаги"
```

а чтобы эта переменная присутствовала и в графических программах, эту же строку можно добавить ещё и, например, в файл `~/.xsessionrc`.

Comment: сложна ;_; очень сложна ;_;

Comment: как прописать из среды ??